# jqPlot target that doesn't have a static id

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm just playing with jqplot for a few hours but I couldn't find how to specify the target in a more specific jquery way.
for example if I have the html code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I can create the chart using

```
 $.jqplot("chart", [], {});
```

and it will create a chart on the element with id: chart.

What I want is to use something like this:

```
$("#chart").jqplot([], {});
```

or

```
 $(".multiple_charts").jqplot([], {});
```

or

```
var myChart=$("<div></div>");
myChart.jqplot([], {});
```

I saw that this problem was already proposed in 2009 here: https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/114/jqplot-target-should-accept-any-element

Is there a solution to what I'm looking for?
 Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at the [code](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/058e50b37d16/src/jqplot.core.js), you could indeed see that `$.jqplot` only accepts the target element's id as first argument, so you're right about that.

However `$.fn.jqplot` is also defined, which means that you *can* use `$(".multiple_charts").jqplot();` or `$("<div></div>").jqplot();`. Note that jqplot creates a unique id for each element in the jquery object if it doesn't already exist.

Oh, **it looks like the version I looked at is not out yet**, but you could just grab the latest code and make a workaround.

Comment: How I can get same `jqplot` object when using `$("...").jqplot();` instead of `$.jqplot(...)` method? I need access to `plugins` property and methods like `destroy()` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up

HTML

```
 <div id="chart2" class="test2" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:460px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Data

```
var data1 = [
            ['Verwerkende industrie', 9], 
            ['Retail', 3], 
            ['Primaire producent', 4], 
            ['Out of home', 2], 
            ['Groothandel', 7], 
            ['Grondstof', 9], 
            ['Consument', 3], 
            ['Bewerkende industrie', 2]
        ];
```

so instead of doing this

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot($('chart2'), [ data1 ], {
            title: ' ', 
            seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false, 
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: { 
                    startAngle: 180, 
                    sliceMargin: 4, 
                    showDataLabels: true
                } 
            }, 
            legend: { 
                show:true, location: 'w' 
            }
        }
    );
```

You can do this

```
$(".test2").jqplot( [data1] , {
            title: ' ', 
            seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false, 
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: { 
                    startAngle: 180, 
                    sliceMargin: 4, 
                    showDataLabels: true
                } 
            }, 
            legend: { 
                show:true, location: 'w' 
            }
        }
    );
```